# how to slide a div in top/left/right/bottom direction on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i need to animate, slide, transition a page in all direction.

i have page in which a container contain three different inner container in bottom and one in the top. first is the left container in green background color. second is the middle container in red background color. and third is the right container in blue background color. and top container have black background color.  in the middle container i have three links.
that is "who we are" , contact us, and what we do.

i need

when i click on who we are... the left container should animate to right and again when i click to who we are button... the left container should animate to left side.

now on contact us link i need to animate middle container in bottom... with toggle case

and on what we do i need to animate the right container in left side with toggle effect.

here is my css

```
body
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.wrapper
{
    width:1366px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.contentwrapper
{
    width:4098px;
    height:665px;
    margin-left:-1366px;
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    position:relative;
}
.topbox
{
    width:1366px;
    height:665px;
    margin:-665px auto 0px auto;
    background:#000;
}

.inner-wrapper
{
    width:1366px;
    height:665px;
    float:left;
}

.bg1
{
    background:#9C0;
}
.bg2
{
    background:url(../images/back1.jpg) center;
}
.bg3
{
    background:#009;
}


.box1
{
    width:280px;
    height:295px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/logo_line.png) no-repeat;
}
.box2
{
    width:280px;
    height:295px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/logo_line.png) no-repeat;
}
.box3
{
    width:280px;
    height:295px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/logo_line.png) no-repeat;
}
```

and here is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AR</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$("#toright").ready(function(){
    var m=0, dir=true;

    $("#toright").click(function() {
        dir = !dir;
        m = dir? -500 : 0;
        $(".contentwrapper").stop().animate({right: m+'px'}, 800);
    });
});
</script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$("#toleft").ready(function(){
    var m=0, dir=true;

    $("#toleft").click(function() {
        dir = !dir;
        m = dir? -500 : 0;
        $(".contentwrapper").stop().animate({left: m+'px'}, 800);
    });
});
</script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$("#totop").ready(function(){
    var m=0, dir=true;

    $("#totop").click(function() {
        dir = !dir;
        m = dir? -500 : 0;
        $(".contentwrapper").stop().animate({bottom: m+'px'}, 800);
    });
});
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contentwrapper">

        <div class="topbox"></div><!--top black box -->

        <div class="inner-wrapper bg1"></div><!--left box -->

        <div class="inner-wrapper bg2"> <!--middle box -->
            <a href="#" class="box1" id="toright"><span>Who We Are</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="box2" id="totop"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="box3" id="toleft"><span>What We Do</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-wrapper bg3"></div> <!--right box -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have each function contained in it's own `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI toggle() animation: http://jqueryui.com/toggle/

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

Comment: thanks @tekoyaki but toggle effect totally hide a container when i click on button